# integration wpbakery page builder in theme development

Tags: wordpress, themes, wpbakery

this is the first time i am trying to make wordpress theme and i have made it all but i am stuck on page builder. I want my user to edit my theme with wp bakery page builder. I have seen many videos and read many blogs but no one satisfied me because my question is very simple.
I want to integrate wpbakery page builder in my theme so when someone download my theme, the wpbakery page builder should download automatically. to get this what should i do ? i saw some themes have this option when i download their themes there was wpbakery page builder already in the theme. how are they achieving this ?
I am sorry i am asking silly question but i did not find this answer in any platform. please share some links too so i can learn this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TGM plugin is generally used in many themes to define suggested and required plugins for themes.

You can find the GitHub Repo here: https://github.com/TGMPA/TGM-Plugin-Activation and check the `example.php` file to understand the implementation based on external and internal plugin zip files.

You can also read the installation process here http://tgmpluginactivation.com/installation/

Or you can check the source code of other themes that use TGM plugin, and you can learn the code writing from those themes.

Comment: thanks. i totally understand your answer but i just saw wpbakery is not free plugin and many themes are using it when we download theme the wpbakery downloads automatically. how ? are they buying wpbakery ?

Comment: They buy the plugin and add it inside the theme, so TGM suggests and install the plugin from an internal source, it doesn't download WP Bakery from an external source.

Comment: can you suggest me some tutorial ?

Comment: Find the themes that plugins suggestion and check their source code and learn from them. or find online article on how to use TGM plugin in wordpress